# Scheduling a background task periodically on Android

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-workmanager, android-background

I'm working on an app where I have to read data from multiple sensors and send it to a remote server every 15 minutes. This has to be done when the app is closed/killed as well and I also have to be sure it always executes. I also want to be sure it happens (almost) exactly every 15 minutes (+-1 minute difference is the upper limit).

At this point, I've found 3 options: using Workmanager, Alarmmanager or using a foreground service. Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), Workmanager seems the way to go for background tasks, however, after having done some reading, Alarmmanager seems to be a safer choice (Workmanager sometimes has troubles with doze mode, and the timing isn't exact because [it uses a flex period](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%20java.time.Duration,%20java.time.Duration)) of at least 5 minutes). And a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#replacing-foregound) is not really allowed for this kind of task (it's not really long running, it's just a periodic task) and is being limited in newer Android versions. Do you think it would be a good idea to use an Alarmmanger for this task, or should I use something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**TODO** Background scheduling.. You can use this method todo your stuff..

**KOTLIN;**

```
val service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate({
            handler.run {
                // Do your stuff here, It gets loop every 15 Minutes
            }
        }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

**JAVA;**

```
  ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            handler.post(() -> {
                // Do your stuff here, It gets loop every 15 Minutes
            });
        }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Is this method still run every 15 minutes although the app / activity is closed / killed ?

Comment: @Plugie YEP! It's not a foreground or background service. it's just a simple code snippet to schedule some jobs. If you want to run scheduled foreground/background service you can use Work Manager Api! - Thanks.